# Add warning to edit slug/permalink button on editor screen.

Tags: slug, visual-editor

I want users to get a warning popup when they click the button to change the permalink. They will give confirmation if they want to continue.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
//Setting a variable for the button Class.
var editSlug = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-slug");

//Detecting when the button is clicked.
editSlug[0].addEventListener ( "click", function() {

//Returning the value of the popup.
return confirm('Warning: Don't do this unless you have to.');

});
```

The issue I am having, is even when clicking cancel, it still allows me to edit the link of my post. If I select cancel, it supposed to return a false value and cancel the event of clicking the edit button. This works fine for other buttons on WP, such as publish, update, etc.

I also am only able to generate the popup once after the page loads, if I select an answer and click edit again, I don't receive any more popups.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress has already hooked jQuery events to that button which you could omit with [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method, or keep things simple and add an overlay above that button and act as the button, prompting users to confirm the editing action at first place:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var c = $('#edit-slug-buttons')
      , b = $('button',c).first();

    c.css({
        position: 'relative'
    }).append('<span class="se-overlay" style=" position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 4px 0; margin-top: -3px; cursor: pointer"></span>');


    $(document).on("click", "#edit-slug-buttons .se-overlay", function(e){
        if ( confirm("Warning: Don't do this unless you have to.") ) {
            $(this).closest('#edit-slug-buttons').children('button').first().trigger('click');
        }
        return e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.